# How to use "plugin_classmap.php" in zf2

Tags: zend-framework2

I have create "plugin_classmap.php" by "pluginmap_generator.php" in ZF2,but how to use it ?
In addition,I have been doing according to this post zf2 performance optimization (http://hounddog.github.io/blog/performance-in-zend-framework-2/).
 is there any other way, please, my program run on ARM is too slow,

Comment: Running on "ARM" - Raspberry? You should not expect good performance from any ARM based system. As far as the Raspberry is concerned I never managed to go below 300ms. Same application runs 20ms on a proper server.

Comment: Much lower than the Raspberry performance of ARM,You are right..

Answer (score 0):

In your Module.php you go like this:

```
class Module
{
        public function getAutoloaderConfig ()
        {
                return ['Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader' => __DIR__ . '/config/autoload_classmap.php'];
        }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, in addition to autoload_classmap.php using loading way, I also want to know plugin_classmap.php How to use and loading.  Here is the  Part of the __plugin_classmap.php__

Comment: `<?php

        // plugin class map  
        // auto-generated using pluginmap_generator.php, 2014-01-24 06:56:44  

    return array (
      'abstractadapter' =>       'Zend\\Validator\\Barcode\\AbstractAdapter',
  'adapterinterface' =>   'Zend\\Validator\\Barcode\\AdapterInterface',
  'callbackcheckadapter' =>       'Zend\\Authentication\\Adapter\\DbTable\\CallbackCheckAdapter',`